# Integrate Squid Kerberos auth and Squidguard ldapusersearch into AD

Tags: linux, ldap, squid, kerberos

I'm having trouble with Squid Kerberos auth and the Squidguard ldapusersearch that I use to apply ACLs by Active Directory groups membership.

The problem is :

- Squid and Squidguard see my user as : `user@domain.local` so **the '%s' variable of squidguard is `'user@domain.local'`**
- In my ldap query there is no default property that can interpret this string.

Example :

```
src ldap {
        ldapusersearch ldap://dc1.domain.local:3268/dc=domain,dc=local?sAMAccountName?sub?(&(sAMAccountName=%s)(memberOf=CN=group,OU=Groups,DC=domain,DC=local))
}
```

**And sAMAccountName should be only `'user'` and not `'user@domain.local'` !!!**

So I found a solution but It's not very comfortable :

I edit an unused attribute of the AD user and I write into it my kerberos login so my conf looks like this :

```
src ldap {
        ldapusersearch ldap://dc1.domain.local:3268/dc=domain,dc=local?displayNamePrintable?sub?(&(displayNamePrintable=%s)(memberOf=CN=group,OU=Groups,DC=domain,DC=local))
}
```

And it works !!!

Anyone have an idea to bypass the need to create a custom attribute in AD who contents ?

And by the way `userPrincipalName` is the same as the email and can't interpret Kerberos login.

Answer (score 1):

I got this to work in my environment by querying LDAP for the userPrincipalName instead of sAMAccountName as my squid also returns user@domain.local from Kerberos/NTLM auth.

Also be sure to use %20 instead of spaces and when I was specifying the bind DN in my conf file, I used quotes as it had an & in the DN and squidguard was not binding because of it.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the "userlist = userlist" (/ var / squidGuard / userlist) instead of "user = foo bar"

Comment: Please explain how this is going to resolve the problem.